# How to build and run a dotnet core project with a .bat file?

Tags: batch-file, .net-core

I am trying to figure out how to do so for a batch file that can be ran on startup of my PC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `dotnet-build` and `dotnet-run` commands.

- **dotnet-build**: builds a project and all of its dependencies.
- **dotnet-run**: provides a convenient option to run your application from the source code with one command.

For more information, refer these links- 
[dotnet-build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-build) and 
[dotnet-run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tools/dotnet-run).